# How to use Zurb Foundation in conjunction with Codekit.

Tags: zurb-foundation, codekit

I'd like to use zurb foundation (SCSS) in conjunction with codekit on my laptop, currently running mavericks but I'm unable to do so once I try to use the compass

I've installed the required gems:

- sudo gem install sass
- sudo gem install compass
- gem install zurb-foundation
- sudo gem environment .

I open codekit, open preferences, click sass/scss and select the 'use the sass executable at this path' then proceed to choose 'sass' from the bin folder.

When I try to do the same process for compass, the compass file isn't present in the bin folder.

I've attempted to locate it elsewhere but I've been unable to do so.

Has anyone else encountered this problem/anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try install foundation using Bower and then just include foundation classes into your main styles file. For me it works great with a codekit.